# How to only check SelectedIndex value in GridView while going from one page to the next

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am working with a classic ASP.NET WebForms page with a GridView. This page has a scrollable table where rows can be selected via a radio button. My problem is that when a radio button is selected a PostBack is made to the server to keep track of the selected value. This makes the page jump back to the value that is selected.

Is there a way to only check the Selected Value once I go from the page with the GridView to the next?

I tried to use the IsValid method which is called after the page is submitted, but since the selected index value is bound in PreRender event it is called everytime a new radio button is selected and the page jumps.

On the GridView I set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and I removed the OnSelectedIndex changed event. Unfortunately, a PostBack keeps happening. And even worse, since the GridView is made scrollable serverside only on first load in OnLoad method (`if (!PostBack) GridViewHelper.Scrollable(MyGridView)`) the scrollability is lost.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: A code snippet would help. I would think that you would put autopostback="false" for you radio button so that you dont fire a post back when it selected. Then when you fire the "PageIndexChanging" when you paginate on the gridview. In the PageIndexChanging I would then go through the rows and see which rows had the radio button selected.

Comment: @MatthewWong Difficult to add a  code snippet since I am not sure where to look. I added an UpdatePanel around it and now the PostBack does not happen, but the scrollable JavaScript is not added either. How do I add autopostback is false to radio button?

Comment: Here's some code on the Data Binding radio button: `GridViewRowSelector radio = (GridViewRowSelector)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("RadioMyObjects");
                
                radio.Checked = false;`

Comment: when you have an update panel you have to do updatepanel.update() wherever you are updating your gridview.

Comment: is your radio button a asp:radiobutton?

Comment: I did that, but the JavaScript is not added.

Comment: Is your js inside your update panel? if so I would suggest doing ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertScript", "alert('Alter From asp.net page');", true); when you do your updatepanel.update. That way you re register your script

Comment: Not sure where it is generated. The radiobutton is not an asp:radiobutton I believe.

Comment: try adding the scriptmanager code i added above to see if your javascript gets re registered when you do an update panel. update()

Comment: They are all re-registered via a method. This method is called, I see the ScriptManager.Register[All kind of things] there.

Comment: Can you post snippets of code. IE: Your Update panel and grid view. Your Pre render, the method that registers your scripts, and where you are saving your values. I think that could help seeing where the problem is =)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53837/discussion-between-user2609980-and-matthew-wong)